# TBindScope missing in XE6 IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, livebindings

TBindScope component exist in XE4 and XE5 IDE but is missing in my XE6's tool palette.

Is this component deprecated?

Comment: It's not deprecated but it seems odd that it's no longer on the palette.

Comment: It is documented in XE3, and removed from docwiki documentation in XE4 and onwards, yet still on the palette in XE4 and XE5?

Comment: @WarrenP: TBindScope is in XE4, XE5 and XE6's docwiki.

Comment: Reported to [QC#126947](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx/qcmain.aspx?d=126947)

Comment: Ok found it. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.Bind.Components.TBindScope

Comment: Tomohiro Takahashi replied in QC#126947 that TBindScope is no longer available for design time.  If this is the case, any workaround solution if I want to use TBindscope.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang:
1. it seems QC#126947 has not been reported on https://quality.embarcadero.com/ -> ?
2. any news on the TBindScope workaround?
3. in the RAD Studio 10.4, TBindScope declared in Data.Bind.Components.pas, but the component is not installed

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not deprecated. It disappeared for some reason, until Embarcadero put it on again in RAD Studio 10.4.1.

Go [there](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/New_features_and_customer_reported_issues_fixed_in_RAD_Studio_10.4.1), and search TBindScope.